# Prepopulate a SlugField in Django from the User model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

For the purposes of having user profiles I'd like to have unique slugs generated using the username field that is stored in the User object. I want to enforce this both in the Admin interface and upon User object creation.

This is what I wanted to use on creation of the User object, and it fails silently (no slug is generated).

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
    super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is how I intended to pre-populate in the admin interface. This fails spectacularly.

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('model.user.username',)}
```

I've noticed there's thousands of articles explaining how to do this however I haven't yet found one explaining how to accomplish this using a field from the User model.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you set an additional `SlugField` on `UserProfile` when you can just access the related `user.slug` value? Additionally, `prepopulated_fields` basically sets up some JavaScript on the client side to copy non-trivial characters from one field to another. It needs direct access to the `username` field, not the related model.

Comment: By  `user.slug` I'm assuming you mean `user.username`. Regardless...I'm not quite sure why I thought it was necessary...force of habit I guess. You're definitely right. Thanks for explaining how the pre-populated fields works. It did seem like a bit of magic :p. You're a king among men @Brandon

Comment: Sorry - I need more coffee. Yes, the `user.username` field has the same unique constraint that a slugfield does, so it's basically the same thing.